# Sort array of strings with special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3 how do I sort an array of strings with special characters.

I have:

```
[Água, Electricidade, Telefone, Internet, Televisão, Gás, Renda]
```

However when i invoke `sort` over the array `Água` gets sent to the end of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I used when I ran into the same issue (depends on **iconv** gem):

```
require 'iconv'

def sort_alphabetical(words)
  # caching and api-wrapper
  transliterations = {}

  transliterate = lambda do |w|
    transliterations[w] ||= Iconv.iconv('ascii//ignore//translit', 'utf-8', w).to_s
  end

  words.sort do |w1,w2|
    transliterate.call(w1) <=> transliterate.call(w2)
  end
end

sorted = sort_alphabetical(...)
```

An alternative would be to use the [sort_alphabetical](http://github.com/grosser/sort_alphabetical) gem.

Comment: If I store this in the ApplicationHelper will it be available accross all views and controllers?

Comment: Only in views. You could put it into a file in the `lib` folder (don't forget to require the file it in your `application.rb`) and monkeypatch the `Array` class.

Answer (score 2):

here's my approach:

```
class String
  def to_canonical
    self.gsub(/[áàâãä]/,'a').gsub(/[ÁÀÂÃÄ]/,'A')
  end
end

['Água', 'Electricidade', 'Telefone', 'Internet', 'Televisão', 'Gás', 'Renda'].sort {|x,y| x.to_canonical <=> y.to_canonical}
```

this proves to be usefull for other regexp aswell, the to_canonical method can be implemented they way that best suits you, in this example just covered those 2 regexp.

hope this alternative helps. 
:)